# What is the correct naming convention for an array vs an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, naming-conventions

What's the naming convention used in JavaScript to distinguish an array from an object? Let's say you have an object that contains error messages (ex. `{'password': 'is less than 8 characters'}`). Would you call this variable, `errorMessages`? If so, what if you had an array where each item is a string and an error message as such: `['password is less than 8 characters', 'password does not match password confirmation']`? What would you call this array? Would you call it `errorMessages`?
If so, then that's confusing because its not clear from the name whether or not the variable is an array or an object.

Comment: I don't think there is a convention for that. At least not that I have heard of.

Comment: You should name it whatever explains best what it contains. Following the camelCasing rules, of course.

Comment: AFAIK there’s no widely used such convention, but nothing prevents you from giving more descriptive names to your variables, e.g. errorMessagesMap or errorMessagesArray.

Comment: actually i read a lot about how var, obj, function and so on should be named for better readibility, and for me works the best thisIsFunction, this_is_var, this_is_obj_obj, this_is_array_arr I think it clear

Comment: @jcaron I like that! `errorMessagesMap` vs `errorMessagesList`.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp) one is the naming convention for W3.

As they remark:

> - Variable and function names written as camelCase
> - Global variables written in UPPERCASE (We don't, but it's quite common)
> - Constants (like PI) written in UPPERCASE

Then, as the array and the variable are both Not CONSTANTS, **maybe you can use PascalCase for Arrays and camelCase for standar variables.**

> **PascalCase**:
>
> PascalCase is often preferred by C programmers.
>
> **camelCase**:
>
> camelCase is used by JavaScript itself, by jQuery, and other
> JavaScript libraries.

Hope it helps

Comment: Conventionally in JavaScript names starting with upper-case letters are used to indicate constructor functions (like the built-in `Array`, `Object`, `Number`, etc).

Comment: Sure, totally agree, but the constructor should go with the parenthesis, and it´s obvius it´s not a built-in Type... then it could be a solution

Comment: Documentation is appreciated, but this does not answer the question. The question is what's the naming convention of a variable for an array vs object. They both can convey plural so how do you distinguish by variable name alone that the variable is an array vs object?

Comment: an "object" will never be plural.. should be an arrray of objects then.. If your are creating a plural object... I reallly don´t understand. I think your problem is not they are arrays nor objects. The real problem is that you are trying to name two things with the same name. Then, as @jcaron said, this is also a convention you can follow. But it will be YOUR/OURS convention, not a convention widely used. I just posted the documentation as it´s the page where I check the conventions for that, supposing it was going to help

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz I am not too sure if I agree. Objects in javascript can be used as 'collections of data which are ordered by key' (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections). I know the link is referencing a `Map` but whatever. An object `{}` can be used like a map in JS. So objects and arrays in JS can be thought of and used as collections. They just function differently. However, I do agree that this will be MY convention, and I do not propose changing how other people should write their JS.